# "Out of gas" error trying to claim EOS tokens

Tags: blockchain, dapps, ico

I participated in eos token distribution few hours back and got the token too. However not able to claim the allocated token.  Tried three time, it gave error `"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas] "`, so lost money on gas thrice.Appreciate any help to claim the token. Here are the transaction #
0x6e3d9b211feda395b939297db06b3d12df70e25ced4c0d5212f5cf06bccdf161
0x83934785d7817a7f06f01449728d8c2889e1bb815e690bcfc36d8db16858231f
0xf8f12936029cdebf1604523bd35a56dc965c4c3d1a2e4a913e65b2549b123c57

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using their distribution tool to generate the transaction?  Or are you creating the transaction yourself manually?

Comment: I used https://eos.io/distribution/. Here we got "Claim EOS Token" link and I used that.

Comment: Weird.  You'd think that would work.  Next id' try creating the transaction yourself based on their instructions.  https://eos.io/instructions.  You could use the parity wallet or MEW wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Lower the gas *price* (to 2 Gwei) or try "claim" instead of "claimAll".  Also, try increasing gas limit to 4,000,000 or so (only with 2 Gwei price though, since TX cost is price * limit).